# understanding gem spec versions

Tags: ruby, rubygems, dependencies

I'm using the compass ruby gem (version 0.7.11), and when I run `gem spec compass`, part of the output is:

```
dependencies:
- !ruby/object:Gem::Dependency
  name: sass
  requirement: !ruby/object:Gem::Requirement
    none: false
    requirements:
    - - ~>
      - !ruby/object:Gem::Version
        version: '3.1'
  type: :runtime
  prerelease: false
  version_requirements: !ruby/object:Gem::Requirement
    none: false
    requirements:
    - - ~>
      - !ruby/object:Gem::Version
        version: '3.1'
```

When I run `gem install compass -v 0.7.11` it does install the correct version of compass, but it's pulling in sass 3.2. I thought the `~>` would keep it in the 3.1.x range. Can someone explain what is happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jeff,

the syntax `~>` shows a dependency discarding the smallest version digit, so `~> 3.1` means, you get every version up to `4.0`.

Notice, that the last digit matters. Say you write `~> 3.1.0`, in that case you'll get every version up to `3.2.0`.

Please look up some other ideas on `~>` (aka `twiddle-wakka`) [here](http://guides.rubygems.org/patterns/).